# Python: Compare each row in df to all rows in another df, element-wise; ML: Similarity for categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I have a data frame with new stores:

```
stores_new = pd.DataFrame({
'id_store': [11, 12, 13], 
'size': [5, 5, 6], 
'location': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa']})
```

And another dataframe with already existing stores:

```
stores_old = pd.DataFrame({
'id_store': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'size': [4, 5, 5, 3, 7],
 'location': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'],
 'sales': [5555, 11111, 6666, 5555, 2222]})
```

I would like to find 3 old stores most similar to each of the new stores and get the average of the sales. Currently, I have created functions for basic 0/1 comparison of each categorical variable and difference for numerical variables which are scaled using MinMaxScaler.

```
def numerical_data(point, data):
    count = [(sum(abs(a-b) for a, b in zip(point, sublist))) for sublist in data.values]
    return count

def categorical_data(point, data):
    count = [(sum(0.5 for a, b in zip(point, sublist) if a != b)) for sublist in data.values]
    return count
```

Now I have two questions:

1. How to implement the current approach without using a loop? So that for each of the new stores it calculates the distance based on all of the old stores. I know it isn't good to use iterrows for df. Df with old stores contains over a thousand stores and each has 15 variables.
2. Is there a better way to implement such an algorithm for numerical and categorical data?

The desired result is a df that looks like this:

```
stores_new_sales = ({'id_store': [11, 12, 13], 'sales': [5925.33, 2962.67, 5925.33]})
```

Comment: What numerical values are you comparing? The size?

Comment: In this case yes, in a real example, there are more variables like population_size or store_area. As I mentioned I use MinMaxScaler to have them all in [0-1] range

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into scipy's `pdist` function for this ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy-spatial-distance-pdist)), it computes pairwise distances between two collections of vectors. You'd need to get your data frames set up in the way you want, and then I'd use `.values` to get just the arrays of data from the data frames.

You might also want to have a look at the nearest neighbors implementation from scikit-learn ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html)). It provides a nice interface for fitting and querying from a nearest-neighbors model, so you could, e.g., get the 3 nearest neighbors from the old stores for each new store, and average those sales.

As you pointed out in the comments, these solutions won't work out of the box for string-valued or categorical variables. One potential solution to this issue is to create 0/1 features (columns in your data frame) for each categorical value, e.g., `location_aaa`, `location_bbb` and so on. This can explode the size of your frames, but it's a potential way to include such variables.

Comment: However, I think neither of them works for categorical data or data with strings.

Comment: But my main problem is how to iterate over the new stores df without using the loop and calculate distances from all old stores?